# Can't read XML file. (file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection timed out)

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read an `XML` file with `php` and print it as a `JSON` file, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://193.190.76.149:81/ParkoParkings/states.php): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /customers/2/9/e/viktordebock.be/httpd.www/parca/index.php on line 7 false
```

The `xml` file I'm trying to parse is:

```
(http://193.190.76.149:81/ParkoParkings/states.php)
```

When I'm testing the same code with a different URL(http://www.parkodata.be/OpenData/ParkoInfo.xml) , everything works fine.

Is it because the first url is an ip-address?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    function Parse ($url) {

        $fileContents = file_get_contents($url);
        $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
        $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));

        $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
        $json = json_encode($simpleXml);

        return $json;

    }

    print Parse("http://193.190.76.149:81/ParkoParkings/states.php");

?>
```

Comment: Works fine for me! Please put error reporting at the top of your file and tell us what error you get! (`<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`) See it just works fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/aKkHPk

Comment: I uploaded the code to another hosting and it's finally working. Thanks for testing my code!

Comment: So your problem is solved? (Made a answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine! But you can add error reporting at the top of your file and check if you get any errors!

Otherwise try it again!

Code:

```
<?php

    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    function Parse ($url) {

        $fileContents = file_get_contents($url);
        $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
        $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));

        $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
        $json = json_encode($simpleXml);

        return $json;

    }

    echo Parse("http://193.190.76.149:81/ParkoParkings/states.php");

?>
```

Output:

```
{"parking":["P Veemarkt","P Schouwburg","P Broeltorens"]}
```

See it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/SFVtQA

Answer (score 0):

`PHP file_get_contents()` doc: 'An E_WARNING level error is generated if filename cannot be found,'

Despite the error you are getting, this may be a 404. Try browsing to the original page yourself.